# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not a delegate type on Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why do I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not a delegate type [TokenAuthWebApiCore.Server]

on this line of code:

```
public virtual void SetUpDataBase(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<SecurityContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecurityConnection"), sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("TokenAuthWebApiCore.Server")));
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc();

    SetUpDataBase(services);

    // services.AddDbContext<SecurityContext>(options =>
    //      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecurityConnection"), sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("TokenAuthWebApiCore.Server")));

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public virtual void SetUpDataBase(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<SecurityContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecurityConnection"), sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("TokenAuthWebApiCore.Server")));
}
```

This are all my using statements

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
```

I am thinking probably this is because the tutorial I am following a tutorial for a different version of .net core and I am using .net core version 2.2. Can you please show me how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SecurityContext` is not a DbContext. If you have a DbContext called `SecurityContext` in your project, remove `using System.Security;` from your usings  in your `Startups.cs`class or rename the DbContext to something like `SecurityDbContext`.

The generic type you are using when calling `AddDbContext` is from the `System.Security` namespace, but it should be your Database context.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error in my project. The problem was that my context class was not derived from DbContext.

```
public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I´ve had the same issue. I use an interface, which is implemented by my DbContext. This solved the problem for me:

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseNpgsql("MyConnectionString", opt => opt.UseNodaTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not about version compatibility error.You need to implement DbContext in your project. When you make context class, you need to inherit context class from DbContext class.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeContext"));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this when I accidentally installed [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) instead of [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.0.0-preview6.19304.10) in my data project.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, when migrating a project to EF core. What happened is that the DB context was still defined for EF. To fix it, I changed the DbContext to include EF core, and added the DbContextOptions constructor.

Full explenation over at the [aspnetcore site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=netcore-cli).

Answer (score 0):

I had EntityFramework & EntityFrameworkCore installed, removed EntityFramework & it was sorted