# Error:Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not of delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Getting the following error:

> Cannot convert lambdaexpression to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not of delegate type

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeContext"));
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684726/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-servicelifetime-because-it-is-not-a-d